# How can I solve on delete no action or on update no action problen when using code-first in Entity Framework with authentication

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, authentication

I'm creating a project for hospital automation in user authentication and using code-first in Entity Framework.

Here my `Hospital` entity:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Here my `Clinic` entity:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

And my `HospitalAndClinic` entity:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HospitalId { get; set; }
    public int ClinicId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HospitalId")]
    public Hospital Hospital { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClinicId")]
    public Clinic Clinic { get; set; }
```

This is the `Doctor` entity:

```
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public int? HospitalAndClinicId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HospitalAndClinicId")]
    public HospitalAndClinic HospitalAndClinic { get; set; }
```

This is my employee entity

```
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int HospitalAndClinicId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HospitalAndClinicId")]
    public HospitalAndClinic HospitalAndClinic { get; set; }
```

My `Doctor`and 'Employee' tables extend from `Person` class that has fields like `id`, `name` etc.

When I do migration I get this problem

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Doctor_HospitalAndClinic_HospitalAndClinicId' on table 'Doctor' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

How can I solve this?

Comment: are you sure you posted all the `properties` defined in each entity? This error is not hard to understand. Theoretically I would say when a `HospitalAndClinic` is deleted, there will be at least 2 cascading paths to delete **one same** dependant. However I cannot see those paths from the code you posted.

Comment: no i didnt post all entities, but if i use these entity also get these error.

Comment: you need to post all the entity classes that have FK to the `HospitalAndClinic`. We may help you understand the cause of the error. Then you can even change your model if possible to fix the error.The answer below is fine but only in case you understand well how it affects the entity deletion logic. More specifically once a `HospitalAndClinic` is deleted, all the other entities referencing to it (via the FK) will be left unchanged (so the FK becomes meaningless) if the FK is optional. In case the FK is required, there will still be another error thrown complaining about...

Comment: ... the FK pointing to a non-existent entity (`HospitalAndClinic`)

Comment: i have updated.

Comment: what is your ef model scheme? (TPH - table per hierarchy, TPT - table per type or TPC - table per concrete type). I guess that your `Doctor` and `Employee` are mapped to one same table? (TPH) and of course a doctor is also an employee (so sharing the same Id). For the other cases, it may be more complicated to find out the circular/multiple cascading paths (you may need to post the base class `Person` as well). If using TPC, there should not be a problem, looks like you're applying TPH or TPT on the `Doctor` and `Employee` models.

Comment: anyway (TPH or TPT), you can try moving this `public HospitalAndClinic HospitalAndClinic { get; set; }` (from both `Doctor` and `Employee`) to the base class `Person` and see if it resolves the error (note that first try temporarily commenting out what you applied in the migration file as suggested by the first answer below). Again, if you don't need to cascade the deletion once `HospitalAndClinic` is deleted (and the FKs are optional), you can apply that answer right away. I'm just trying to help you understand the issue, finally you will have the answer.

Comment: i'm using TCP and also have patient tablo cause of that i dont move that public HospitalAndClinic HospitalAndClinic { get; set; } to person entity. in context class i dont set person class i guess that is TCP.

Comment: you don't have to guess it, your models & the mapped tables will show the scheme clearly. Do the `Doctor` and `Employee` have its own separate table? Do you have a `Person` table as well?

Comment: Yes Doctor and Employee have its own separate table and have own person table's props. No i dont have person table i dont need it

Comment: well so it's clearly a `TPC`, so with all what you provided I still could not see the possible circular/multiple cascading paths, unless it may involve some hidden inherited properties from the `Person` entity.

Comment: My Person entity have fk from City entity. might it be problem?

Comment: I don't think so, but it depends on what in the `City` entity. In short, you can imagine that the cascading paths are formed by `FKs`, so you trace the FKs to find the paths.

Comment: how can i solve these problems?

Comment: I don't know, first you need to find out the circular/multiple cascading paths (from the `HospitalAndClinic`) but as I said I could not find them with what you provided. You can try applying the answer below and try deleting a `HospitalAndClinic` (with test data, including data for all kinds of entities) to see if there is any error. Dependant entities (that are not deleted by cascading) may become redundant (garbage) data.

Answer (score 1):

In the `migration`, under `constrains` you can add `onDelete` property to say what happens when deleted.

```
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Doctor",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                .
                .
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Doctor", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Doctor_HospitalAndClinic_HospitalAndClinicId",
                    column: x => x.HospitalAndClinicId,
                    principalTable: "HospitalAndClinic",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);  // <---- Add this.
            });
```

Or what you can also do is, as `Hopeless` pointed out, use fluent API to configure your model by overriding the `OnModelCreating` method in your derived context.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>()
    .HasOne(e => e.HospitalAndClinic)
    .WithMany()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction); // <-- Add this
```

Visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-5.0) to see all `DeleteBehaviors` and visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.referentialaction?view=efcore-5.0) to see all `ReferentialActions`

Comment: You don't have to modify the generated migration file. Just add option in the OnModelCreating. Anyway doing like this may be something unexpected by the OP. The point here is to make it clear about the cause of the error so that we can change the model design (if possible). Deletion cascading may be important so disabling it should be considered carefully (to have alternative handling when deletion happens)

Comment: @SametErtas Consider accepting it as answer if it worked.